# Can't Center the scene to the screen in Godot?

Tags: android, mobile, godot

I have few scenes in my project. I was able to center all of the other scenes. But i cannot center the main scene in my project. Its fine when it opened on a mobile device(probably because resolution matches i guess). but when i opened it in tablet(its an old tab "xiaomi tab 3") its always align to the right on the screen. I was able to center other scenes but i cant center the main scene to screen for some reason. project setting set as 2D and Expand. I also tried to use Control nod, canves layers, margine containers.. but nothing works. If someone can give any suggestions, Thank you in advance.
[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJOHl.jpg)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJOHl.jpg

project
1920 x 1080

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem, or similar, in windowed mode. I don't know if this is the exact case, but if it doesn't mess with your project, try full-screen mode.

If it's that, you can also take care of the window bar size (which is a problem because it can change from different devices), since godot will count its pixels too.

Notice that you're only having this problem in one axis.

Also, I think you could take a look into the Viewport Stretch Mode. It could mess your graphics depending of the intended result—but other projects won't even notice, so judge for yourself.

> The viewport setting sets the root scene’s Viewport to the base resolution. The rendered output of the root Viewport is then scaled to the display resolution. [...]
> The viewport setting is a better choice than the 2d setting when pixel-perfect precision is required, since primary rendering still occurs at the base resolution.
> *[Support multiple devices](https://developer.android.com/games/engines/godot/godot-formfactor?hl=zh-cn)*

Scaling correctly for all devices could be an odyssey, so bon voyage.